# How to use audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I created the UIButton with an image on the MainStoryBoard. When I press that button it plays an audio file and while the audio is playing the background color of UIButton changes.

audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying1 is properly called, however audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying2　seems not be called. I appreciate any advise that lead me to solve this problem.

```
    let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
    let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")

    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton2: CustomButton! 

   func Player(url: URL) {
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
            player.play()
            yourButton.isSelected = true
            player.delegate = self
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func Player1(url: URL) {
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
            player.play()
            yourButton2.isSelected = true
            player.delegate = self
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
        Player(url: url1)
    }
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        yourButton.isSelected = false

    }

    @IBAction func pushButton2(sender: UIButton) {
        Player1(url: url2)
    }
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying2(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        yourButton2.isSelected = false
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating  the player locally in the `Player1/Player` methods. so when the method ends the player will be deallocated. Keep the generated player as a class member so it won't be deallocated when the method exits

In your class add:

```
class YourClass
{
    let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
    let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")

    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton2: CustomButton! 

    fileprivate var player1: AVAudioPlayer? 
    fileprivate var player2: AVAudioPlayer?

    .
    .
    .

    func Player(url: URL) {
        do {
            try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
            player1!.play()
            yourButton.isSelected = true
            player1!.delegate = self
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Another thing.. you are using a delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` which is a delegate method of the `AVAudioPlayer`. however `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying2` is not so it is useless here. Since you have two players with one class as the delegate you will need to identify which player has finished and change the correct button.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if (player === player1) {
        yourButton.isSelected = false
    } else if (player === player2) {
        yourButton2.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to write "Keep the generated player as a class member"?

Comment: @risa8 check my edited answer. You can get rid of the method audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying2. read the explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help! :)